# HTML different Styles for two sections

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to know weather there is a way to add two different styles to two code blocks in HTML.
For an example, I have two sections

```
<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </header>
</section>
```

and

```
<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
    </header>
</section>
```

and I want to apply two different styles for above two sections.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: For the styles you can use a different class or an id for each sections and apply each style to the specific class or id. About the scripts, I don't know what do you mean. You can use one script and use only the methods needed in each section.

Comment: I'm using two html templates, One template with a table and it has it's own style classes and java scripts. The other one is a page template and it has it's own classes. I need to add that table into the second template.

Comment: Are these templates editable? Can you not add ID's to the elements you wish to target? What do the scripts do that are included in the template? Can better help you if I know the answers to these questions :)

Comment: Yes the templates are editable. Yes adding ID's is possible. The scripts are used for animations of the table.

Comment: https://codyhouse.co/demo/schedule-template/index.html Here is the Table template I'm going to use. I need to have it inside another template.

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta you have shared a link just now. What is that about? Can you explain? Actually, you are making the question very confusing to me.If you want different style you can simply give `id` or use `nth-child` like other answered. But you are asking to add a table in 2nd template. What you re trying to achieve I am not getting.

Comment: You can see the table template in the above URL, I have another template for the page. I need to use this table inside my page. But since these are templates their style classes and scripts are in two folders. But I need to use both in the same template. Need to know if there's a way to differentiate the two folders by those two sections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a class or id to each of your sections - that's precisely what they're there for.

```css
/* Our base styles*/

section {
 border: dashed 1px black; 
 padding: 1em;
 margin: 1em; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 color: #900;
}


/*Can over ride styles with classes*/

section.type-a {
 background-color: #fee;
 
 border: solid 4px red; 
}

section.type-b {
background-color: #efe;
color: #060;
}
```

```html
<section class="type-a">
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </header>
</section>
<section class="type-b">
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
    </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Actually I'm using two style classes which are not in the same CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got your question now. So, what you can do you can add your table template inside another div and give that a class . Now you can define a style for your `section` and another `section` which is inside the class `second-template`. 
This way you can make the different styling for the same.

Now for the script I have written a sample piece of code. You can change the same accordingly.

```
$('.second-template').find('section').css("color", "green");
```

Try like this:

```js
$('.second-template').find('section').css("color", "green");
```

```css
section {
    background: red;
}

.second-template > section {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </header>
</section>

<div class="second-template">
 /*Include your secoond template here */
 <section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </header>
</section>
 
</div>
```

Comment: OK I'll try that way

Comment: But I need to add scripts too

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta Ok I added a sample of code and I used Jquery to select the section inside the class `second-template` and made the text color  green .The snippet is updated. You can change your script accordingly. Try like it . If you face any issue , let me know with the type of script you are planning to add eg. JS only, Jquery angular so that I can help you properly.

Comment: OK I'll try it out and notify

Answer (score 1):

CSS (except for [scoped](https://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) and [contained](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-containment) CSS, which have little browser support) and JS are applied at the document level.

To limit them to a specific region of the document, you have to design the CSS and JS to work that way. Typically you would access all your elements with selectors that are prefixed with an [ID selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) (after adding an `id` attribute to the outermost element in each of the groups you are working with) and [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) (in the selector for the CSS rule-set or in the argument to `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` respectively).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nth-of-type()` selector  :

```
section:nth-of-type(index){
   //Your rules
}
```

Example:

```css
section:nth-of-type(1){
   color: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(2){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </header>
</section>

<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
    </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Can use this method for only one CSS file but I have two CSS files here. And also I need to add two scripts from two different files

Comment: I'll try this way too for CSS. But I need a way to add scripts too

Answer (score 1):

use the CSS3 :nth-child() Selector as indicated below

```
section:nth-child(1) {
    //apply your changes to the first section
}

section:nth-child(2) {
    //apply your changes to the second section
}
```

Comment: Yes this method can be used if I'm gonna use a single style class. But in my case I have two style classes.

Answer (score 1):

If there is need to reach your different classes, then you need to traverse through the elements as indicated below.
But the key thing is having the reference to the first element using the nth-child selector, i do not see the need to bother with scripts, the code below works for me and applies the different styles to the different elements.

```
<style type="text/css">
    section:nth-child(1) .major{
            background:red;
            height:100px;
            color:#fff;
    }

    section:nth-child(2) .major{
            background:blue;
            height:100px;
            color:lightcyan;
    }
</style>

<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </header>
</section>


<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
    </header>
</section>
```